# Insert json_encode of any emoji to mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, ascii, emoji

I am trying to insert emojis into my SQL table. I have some emojis already inserted in my rows from my table, like these one: ⚽(\u26bd), ⭐(\u2b50) and ⛔ (\u26d4).

I have already tried to insert and update my rows from my table with different emojis, but i can't. I have discovered the reason that MySQL has allow me to insert the other 3 emojis and it's because the codification of they only have one `\`. If i try to insert a different emoji which the ascii codification has more than `\`, the information in the row will magically disappear, or it will be replaced with `????`.

This is my query to update the one row from my table to add an emoji:

```
UPDATE myusers SET name = "\u26bd William" WHERE id = 8
```

If i run the query in my table it will insert in the row name `\u26bd William`, as i want.

But if i try with a different emoji which ascii codification it's like this (\ud83d\ude80)

```
UPDATE myusers SET name = "\ud83d\ude80 William" WHERE id = 8
```

The query in my table it will insert in the row name `ud83dude80William`, or `????William`, or `null`. So in this time i have lost information in my row running that query

I have already tried to change the charset of my table, but it didn't make a difference

Comment: How do you read back the data from the table? In a SQL tool?

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3d7c07b90f2b4db38428d3cfb24d1dc0

Comment: Thanks @Akina, it has worked

Answer (score 1):

Finally to fix this issue (reffer to Akina answer, thanks very much) we have to add in the query double backslash.
Example:

```
UPDATE myusers SET name = "\\ud83d\\ude80 William" WHERE id = 8;
SELECT * FROM myusers;
```